# compare a brush and color

Tags: c#, colors, brush

```
if (backBrush == SystemColors.ActiveCaption)
```

This fails. Says you can't compare a brush and a color.

How do I find the color of the brush?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If backBrush is a SolidColorBrush (based on what you're trying to do it probably is) you can use:

```
if(((SolidColorBrush)backBrush).Color == SystemColors.ActiveCaption)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the brush is a SolidBrush you can compare the Color member of the brush. Something like this.

```
SolidBrush solidBrush = brush as SolidBrush;
if (solidBrush != null && solidBrush.Color == SystemColors.ActiveCaption)
{
  // ....
}
```

The above is for WinForms, for WPF you would use [SolidColorBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx) rather than SolidBrush.

Answer (score 1):

A [`Brush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) does not have a color.

You use a `Brush` *with* a `Color` for filling/painting etc.

*Some* brushes *do* have a color ([`HatchBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.hatchbrush_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has two), so you will need to cast to the type of brush and compare colors then:

```
((HatchBrush)backBrush).BackgroundColor == SystemColors.ActiveCaption
```

Comment: well, to be exact, some brushes *do* have a color... (`SolidColorBrush`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `SystemBrushes` namespace?

```
if (backBrush == SystemBrushes.ActiveCaption)
{...
```